# Hide MVC telerik grid column in javascript cause Alignment Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, telerik-mvc

Hi I'm using "Telerik Extensions for ASP.NET MVC control" in my application. Using javascript I can hide the first column in a grid, but the problem is other columns alignment is totally disturbed. I used the following code to hide the grid column:

```
var grid = $("#ApprovalList").data("tGrid");
grid.hideColumn(0);
```

Using the above code I can hide the column, but all column data move left side and alignment is totally disturbed. Please help. How can I maintain grid column alignment or how I can hide grid column header.

Answer (score 0):

To hide the header for a specific column, in your column definitions put

```
headerAttributes: {style: 'display:none;'}
```

To hide the whole column, what you are doing is correct. What exactly is the undesired behaviour?

Comment: Thank you Mardoxx but I want to hide 1 column in javascript because some users can view this column and some user cann't. So please let me know how I can hide column with header in javascript so that my grid alignment shouldn't disturbed.Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 0):

In Telerik grid's onDataBound event add the following code:

```
if(shouldShow) {
    $('#myGrid th:eq(2)').show();
    $('#myGrid tr').find('td:eq(2)').show();
    $('#myGrid colgroup').find('col:eq(2)').show();
}
else {
    $('#myGrid th:eq(2)').hide();
    $('#myGrid tr').find('td:eq(2)').hide();
    $('#myGrid colgroup').find('col:eq(2)').hide();
}
```